# First time booting up and other log ins look different

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, login-screen, gdm, gnome-tweak-tool

I have installed Ubuntu 19.04 (with GNOME) on my MSI GL62-7QF. By using GNOME Tweaks I managed to install Pop!_OS shell theme, while using the desktop everything works as intended, once I log out the Log In screen looks like Ubuntu's default. I will show some photos to better explain.

What I have done to install the theme was:

1. Installing as mentioned in their Github page: https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-shell-theme
2. Manually deleting the themes I wasn't using (All of them except Pop-light)
3. Selecting shell theme under Gnome Tweaks (with User Shell extension)

Here is how it looks when I boot up and should look like:
[image: POP!_OS shell theme log in]

And here is how it looks after I log out:
[image: Ubuntu shell theme log in]

Comment: @pomsky I think he might need to update the login manger via gnome? does that sound right?

Comment: Looks like this has been a long term bug in Gnome with no known solution. Here is a massive thread of people reporting the problem for two years [Gnome Theme reverting back after logout](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1575703.html) The thread does have some interesting ideas on how to further diagnose the problem, but nobody really seems able to fix it. Bummer. Maybe there is someway to blow out the entire default them from wherever it is storing that config?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Will do some research about that

Comment: Thank you! Will read a little bit in the thread and do some research about what @JoshuaBesneatte commented. If it helps I will confirm your answer.

Comment: I mean grub, not gnome... also, look into something like `update-alternatives --config desktop-splash`

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte It outputs that there are no alternatives...